# what does :: mean when used before std like ::std::mutex

Tags: c++, std

I'm reading mongo resource code, reading `using ::std::mutex`, but I don't know what's the meaning?

```cpp
namespace stdx {

using ::std::mutex;            // NOLINT
using ::std::timed_mutex;      // NOLINT
using ::std::recursive_mutex;  // NOLINT

using ::std::adopt_lock_t;   // NOLINT
using ::std::defer_lock_t;   // NOLINT
using ::std::try_to_lock_t;  // NOLINT

using ::std::lock_guard;   // NOLINT
using ::std::unique_lock;  // NOLINT

}
```

Comment: It means the global namespace

Answer (score 10):

Leading `::` means compiler should start looking for definition of instantiated object from global scope.

Hence `using ::std::mutex` means starting from global scope, go to `std` namespace and use `mutex` class in current namespace `stdx`.

Comment: Correct. This should be the correct answer.

Comment: @MichalŠtein - "Correct" is in part a measure of upvotes. All good answers are correct. The checkmark only means it helped the poster of the question personally. It does not bestow additional "correctness".

Comment: Really? Do you need a screenshot, @StoryTeller, to see that the little checkbox says something about a correct answer when hovered on? Also, did you know that words can have more than one meaning? "Correct" was meant not to signify the correctness of the statements in the answer, but to signify that the answer was what the asker wanted to know. I if I knew you take every word literally, I'd write "an answer that correctly answers the question while being simple and accurate".

Comment: @MichalŠtein - Yes, do please be precise in your language on SO, lest you mislead the uninitiated. That will be better all around.